# TSQL xml.modify replace value for node with value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I need to update a XML node in a SQL Server column.

I see many examples of using an xpath and identifying the node using the attribute.

The XML I am working with is auto generated and does not come with attributes on the nodes I need. How would I construct the update statement to use another value in the node to find it?

I'm hoping to be able to write something like this:

```
declare @xml xml ='
<Content>
<ContentItems>
    <ContentItem>
        <ContentKey>abc</ContentKey>
        <Body>TextToUpdate</Body>
    </ContentItem>
    <ContentItem>
        <ContentKey>efg</ContentKey>
        <Body>Other</Body>
    </ContentItem>
</ContentItems>
</Content>'

select @xml

set @xml.modify(
'
replace value of 
(/content/contentitems[ContentKey="abc"]/body/text())[1]  
with ("Success")')

select @xml
```

Comment: for XML above, what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: The body text of the ContentItem with the ContentKey of 'ABC' is replaced with "Success".  I can't figure out how to "select" the node using the node value since there are no attributes in the xml nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You're in the right direction. Only wrong character-casing, as mentioned in the other answer, and missing `/ContentItem` in the XPath that prevent the original query to work. Fix that and you're good to go :

```
set @xml.modify('
replace value of 
(/Content/ContentItems/ContentItem[ContentKey="abc"]/Body/text())[1]  
with "Success"
')
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** XML is case sensitive.  So you'll want to make sure you're calling out the tags correctly in your XPath.

**Second:** Have a look at this example...

```
set @xml.modify
(
'
    replace value of (/Content/ContentItems/ContentItem/Body/text())[1]  
    with    (
            if (/Content/ContentItems/ContentItem/ContentKey/text() = "abc") then "Success"
            else ""
            )
')

select @xml
```

Comment: Doing some reading on this here I am actually not sure how scalable this solution is.  It works nicely for your XML, but say you were to add another ContentItem with a ContentKey of "abc".  This would only update the first occurrence leaving the rest unchanged.  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2738/examples-of-using-xquery-to-update-xml-data-in-sql-server/